# get data from onclick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

First, my problem is exactly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408493/set-on-item-click-listener-inside-onbindviewholder-with-recyclerview-adapter/34408747), but I still cant solve my problem.

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private static final String TAG = "PlaceAdapter";

  List<PlaceSaved> items;
  PlaceDatabase db;
  public PlacesAdapter(List<PlaceSaved> items, PlaceDatabase db) {
    this.items = items;
    this.db = db;
  }

    @Override
    public PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
          .inflate(R.layout.places_list_item,parent,false);
      return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      holder.name.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
      holder.time.setText(items.get(position).getTime());
      holder.longi.setText(items.get(position).getLongi());
      holder.delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
        //  removeItem(items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
          AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  db.databaseInterface().delete(items.get(position));
                  Snackbar.make(view , items.get(position).getTime()+" deleted, will be updated next time!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });

      holder.cview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("CardView", "Clicked "+items.get(position).getTitle()+", "+items.get(position).getLongi());
        Location Saved_Location_onCard = new Location("");
        Saved_Location_onCard.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(items.get(position).getTitle()));
        Saved_Location_onCard.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(items.get(position).getLongi()));
        latlang.Lat = (Double.parseDouble(items.get(position).getTitle()));
        latlang.Lang = (Double.parseDouble(items.get(position).getLongi()));

        Snackbar.make(view, "The new location is "+
                items.get(position).getTitle()+", "+items.get(position).getLongi(),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        Intent intent = new Intent(, SunFragment.class)
         SecondFragment sf = new SecondFragment();
          sf.updateLocationUI();
//          sf.showMap();
        }
      });
    }
```

After realising that onclick is not a good idea inside `onBindViewHolder`, I am trying to move it to `ViewHolder` as:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener{
      public TextView name;
      public TextView time;
      public TextView longi;
      public ImageButton delbutton;
      public CardView cview;

      public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        time= itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        longi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        delbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delicon);
        cview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_view);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
      }
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view){
        //Snackbar.make(this,"Hi", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("onClick", "Hello"+getLayoutPosition());
      }
    }
```

So, I am abel to get the layout's position, but not the values stored in the card, as I was able to do when I defined it inside BindView.

How I can do that?

Also, any idea how to delete and update the delete function?

Comment: you just want the data that you are binding to the card at the clicked position ryt?? there's no easier question than this

Comment: yes...thats correct.

Comment: checkout the answer below !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the position with `getAdapterPosition()`.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        // Clicked postion 
        int position =getAdapterPosition();
        PlaceSaved place=items.get(position);
        // Here is the data Do your stuff 
    }
```

To delete a specific item with position call.

```
items.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Read Notify methods for `RecyclerView.Adapter`[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I can extract the data now. 
Can you kindly elaborate the delete thing? As commented in the code, the delete doesnt get updated on the same view.

Comment: You need to call notifyItemRemoved with specific position . Read the link attached . Recycler view provide a bunch of methods for notifying adapter as per need .

Comment: thats givin me                                                                      android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.